# Seaborn heatmap not dispalying correctrly

Tags: pandas

**My DF**

- all column type - int64
- no null

[image]

**Heatmap**

sns.heatmap(df_merged1)

**result**

- y-axis - not sync w/  df columns

Why this happens and how can I correct this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not embedding the images. I'm a novice here!

Comment: Can you please post the values of the dataframe as code so we can reproduce and help? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your data covers several dissimilar dynamic ranges. It is not the right kind of data for a heatmap.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to output? This looks normal, most your values are very small considering the maximum of the cmap (300000).

Comment: First you have to ask your self, What's is the objective of a Heatmap on your dataset ?
Show the correlation of your data ?
IF yes. Maybe your first steps are choose what features will be plotted.
You got, Categorical, Dates, Numerical Data with unlike scales.
Assuming if you want show correlation between features:
I recommend, first, choose what data is important.
Second, Normalize this data if possible. Check for z-score or min-max
Than use some correlation to plot.
Like:  sns.heatmap(df_merged1.corr())

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset has a wide range of values, as it seems you have at least one value close to 300000, everything is compressed in the dark shades.

Here is a an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': 0,
                   'col1': np.random.uniform(high=0.1, size=100),
                   'col2': np.random.uniform(high=1, size=100),
                   'col3': np.random.uniform(high=100, size=100),
                   'col4': np.random.uniform(high=1000, size=100),
                  })
```

```
>>> df.head()
   col0      col1      col2       col3        col4
0     0  0.086361  0.608313  35.650984  246.124989
1     0  0.024252  0.385995   5.734007  159.079960
2     0  0.003769  0.545130  86.591072  178.260150
3     0  0.067679  0.774341  66.723193  325.398593
4     0  0.067590  0.950183  66.347411  984.831065
```

Which looks like:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df)
```

[image: raw data]

To view the compressed columns, you have several options.

##### Use a log scale:

```
import numpy as np
sns.heatmap(np.log(df))
```

[image: log scale]

##### standardize the data (e.g., by dividing with max):

```
sns.heatmap(df/df.max())
```

*NB. true standardization would be `(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())`*

[image: standardized data]

*NB2. For "col0" (all zeros), the data appears as NaN (white) due to the division by 0.*